# Wordpress - upload media files doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

I have a few WP sites on my hosting account, and in general they work pretty well.
Except for the fact the the upload section under Media->Library doesn't work. I'm talking about the advanced upload mechanism, the one that I can drag files onto from my local computer and so on.
When I click the button there, nothing happens. The dialog box for selecting files doesn't even open. Dragging file onto this section of the page also does nothing.
The only thing that does work is when I go to Media->Add New, where there is a standard browser file field where I can select a local file for upload.
But this is the old and limited way! This way I can select only 1 file at a time. Also, because of the issue with the advanced upload, I cannot upload files directly into the theme customizer for example, and all other places in the system where I have the option of uploading files directly into the theme, plugin or whatever and not just select it from the existing library.
It is not a matter of permissions on the folders or files of the system, as I have no problem there (full permissions on everything), AND the fact that I CAN upload files through the standard file field proves that. Also, the advanced way doesn't even open the "select files" dialog box, so it never gets to deal with permissions anyway.

This is the section of the admin that I'm talking about:

[image]

And this is the only standard way that works:

[image]

UPDATE:

First of all, I forgot to mention that there is no error in the console of the browser while this situation occurs.

In addition, I have updated Chrome to the latest version (56) and now dragging the files into the upload area magically works all of a sudden.
However, clicking on the "Select Files" still doesn't do anything.
So right now, this situation is much better than before, but uploading files only by dragging them onto the page, without having the option to select them normally from the local computer is a bit of a drag... (sorry for the word game)  :)

Comment: There's a strong possibility you have a JS error preventing you from using the media uploader. Check your console

Answer (score -1):

7 years later but this problem still happens!

I found the solution was to update to latest version of Chrome browser.